# Loop for issue javascript won't run

Tags: javascript, html

So this exercice is about outputing a word by the number typed in the input section simple but i find this problem  the loop for won't work if there is any help i will be greatfull

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <script defer>
        function Verifer() {
            var ch = document.querySelector("input").value
            var nbr = document.getElementById("nb").value
            if ((nbr > 0) && (ch != "")) {
                for (let i = 1; i >= nbr; i++) {
                    var txt = ""
                    txt += "<h1>" + ch + "</h1> <br>"
                    document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = txt
                }
            } else {
                alert("Retype plz")
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    // the first input is to type a String //the seconde input to type the number of repetition of this String
    <strong>Chain :</strong><input type="text" id="chain" maxlength="20"><br>
    <strong>nombre de rep :</strong><input type="number" maxlength="5" id="nb"><br>
    <button type="button" onclick="Verifer()">Envoyer</button>
    <div id="d2">
        //This part is dedicated to the output of the function

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: change ` i>` in `for(let i=1;i>=nbr;i++) to i< `

Comment: What's the values for `i` and `nbr`? This is also a good chance to try out either the debugger or simple `console.log` to make sure your code is doing what you think it is based on your input. And to understand number vs. string comparisons.

Comment: i and nbr are both type integer

Answer (score 4):

change

```
var nbr = document.getElementById("nb").value
```

to

```
var nbr = parseInt(document.getElementById("nb").value)
```

Comment: can  you explain me more why please? 
the number input is already type ="number"

Comment: because you get string value and try to use it as int

Comment: parseInt() will get int value from string

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do? Your question is a bit vague.

```js
function Verifer() {
  var ch = document.querySelector("input").value;
  var nbr = document.getElementById("nb").value;

  nbr = parseInt(nbr); //Parse to int

  console.log(nbr);

  if (nbr === NaN || !ch) { //Validate
    document.getElementById("nb").value = "invalid";
    return;
  }
  
  var txt = ""; //Set var in scope around for loop

  for (var i = 1; i <= nbr; i++) { //repeat when i is less or equal to nbr
    txt += "<h1>" + ch + "</h1> <br>" //Append txt
  }
  
  document.getElementById("d2").innerHTML = txt; //Add txt to element html
}
```

```html
<strong>Chain :</strong><input type="text" id="chain" maxlength="20"><br>
<strong>nombre de rep :</strong><input type="number" maxlength="5" id="nb"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="Verifer()">Envoyer</button>
<div id="d2">

</div>
```